# How to create segmentation after a table is created in Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I work on vertica and it was suggested to us by DWH team to create segmentation while creating the tables for faster execution. We are doing this on new tables but there are a few tables which have historical data stored and we need to create segmentation on them. How can we do it without dropping and creating a new table?

Answer (score 1):

If your Vertica cluster is K-Safe, segmentation will happen by default (on the first 32 columns). You can check which projections are not segmented using:

```
SELECT * FROM v_catalog.projections WHERE NOT is_segmented;
```

However, just because a projection is segmented, does not mean performance will be worse or better.

If you mean to say your DWH team recommended to **partition** tables, then refer to the best practices for [defining partitions](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Partitions/DefiningPartitions.htm). See the [partitioning and segmentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Partitions/PartitioningAndSegmentingData.htm) documentation to understand the difference between partitioning and segmentation.

Comment: one up for @Kermit - it totally depends on your workload if segmentation will be good for you.  segmentation != partitioning(but almost the same) :)